# Google map showing grey bands and looks distorted

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

For some reason, even though my Google map is showing, there are strange grey bands/lines running through the map (image link below).

Just for reference it uses the places API to search for locations.

[Screenshot of the map issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xl9SK.png)

Anybody have any ideas why this might be? Here's the code for the map:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&libraries=places"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function search_map_init() {
        var args     = {
            disableDefaultUI : true,
            center           : new google.maps.LatLng(51.6948168, -0.6433884),
            mapTypeId        : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            scrollwheel      : false,
            zoom             : 12,
            styles           : [{"featureType":"water","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#e9e9e9"},{"lightness":17}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#f5f5f5"},{"lightness":20}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"},{"lightness":17}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"},{"lightness":29},{"weight":0.2}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"},{"lightness":18}]},{"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"},{"lightness":16}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#f5f5f5"},{"lightness":21}]},{"featureType":"poi.park","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#dedede"},{"lightness":21}]},{"elementType":"labels.text.stroke","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#ffffff"},{"lightness":16}]},{"elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"saturation":36},{"color":"#333333"},{"lightness":40}]},{"elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"transit","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#f2f2f2"},{"lightness":19}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#fefefe"},{"lightness":20}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#fefefe"},{"lightness":17},{"weight":1.2}]}]
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), args);

        var marker_url = {
            url        : 'IMG_URL',
            scaledSize : new google.maps.Size(48, 65)
        };

        var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('pac-input'));
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(document.getElementById('pac-input'));

        google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
            searchBox.set('map', null);

            var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            var i, place;
            for (i = 0; place = places[i]; i++) {
                (function(place) {
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

                        position: place.geometry.location,
                        icon     : marker_url
                    });
                    marker.bindTo('map', searchBox, 'map');
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'map_changed', function() {
                        if (!this.getMap()) {
                            this.unbindAll();
                        }
                    });

                    bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
                }(place));

                var new_address = $('#pac-input').val();
                var new_lat     = place.geometry.location.lat();
                var new_lng     = place.geometry.location.lng();

                $('input[name="post[meta_input][map][address]"]').val(new_address);
                $('input[name="post[meta_input][map][lat]"]').val(new_lat);
                $('input[name="post[meta_input][map][lng]"]').val(new_lng);
            }

            map.fitBounds(bounds);
            searchBox.set('map', map);
            map.setZoom(Math.min(map.getZoom(),12));
        });

        return map;
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', search_map_init);
</script>
```

**Note**: I've replaced the API key and image URL with *API_KEY* and *IMG_URL* in the code above.

Comment: Most likely a CSS issue, most likely something to do with image height, but you haven't shared your CSS. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: You are indeed correct. It was an image issue in the CSS. I never really connected the two as being the problem. Thanks for the heads up I’ve found the problem. I was setting min-width on image in a certain section that was also effecting the map!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was setting min-width in the CSS for something else which was also effecting the map display. Problem solved!